# Using Slick.js carousel with centerMode: true and slidesToShow: 2 puts first slide in wrong place

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I'm using Slick (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) with `centerMode: true` and `slidesToShow: 2` to display two full slides at first, centred inside the carousel. I'd like the first fully visible slide to be number 1 and the second to be number 2, but what's happening is that the first fully visible slide is the *last* slide, and the second fully visible slide is number 1...

So a visual example of what's going wrong, in a carousel with 12 slides, would be:

[image: Wrong sequence]

Whilst what I'd like to happen is:

[image: Correct sequence]

I'm using `centerPadding` to show a bit of the preceding and following slides on either side.

Does anyone know if I've missed a setting that controls this?

The carousel spans a full 12 columns inside a Bootstrap grid.

Comment: PS - am aware that this is to "Use with odd numbered slidesToShow counts." but the layout generated with the settings above is perfect, other than the starting position of the first slide in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `initialSlide` option is what you are looking for: `initialSlide: 1` (vs default `0`)